# Triggering signal out when the permission of a SharePoint file is modified

Tags: python, events, sharepoint, webhooks

I have a Python app listening to API calls.
I wish to have API calls sent to this app to trigger some functions inside, once the permission of a SharePoint file is altered e.g. granted write access to group X.

I have tried investigating SharePoint webhooks but it seems to not be triggered by permission changes, only the content and other metadata changes like title.

I do not wish to do a full scan and making a Graph API call for each SharePoint file just to check their permissions, as well as maintaining a separate database to store the old permissions to see if a file's permission has been changed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.